# Audio Recording Semantics Issues

Tags: xcode, audio, avfoundation, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

So I am not very good with computers and have to create my first app for a project. It's going fine so far - essentially I am trying to create an app that records and saves data. Right now I'm still getting the record part down, since Xcode is having periodic issues. I am using this link for setting up the code:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_iOS_7_with_AVAudioRecorder

Unfortunately, I am running into 2 types of semantic errors, two red, two yellow. They are all in RecordModelController.m - the first is like this:

```
return [self.pageData indexOfObject:viewController.dataObject];
```

Xcode claims that Property 'dataObject' isn't found in any object or forward class in 'RecordDataViewController'. That's actually my two red errors, they just sound very similar so I paraphrased them into one. The yellow error, however, repeats itself twice on the same line of code, which is:

```
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController. storyboard];
```

The yellow issues on these lines of code (again, repeated twice) is "Incompatible pointer types returning 'RecordDataViewController *' from a function with result type 'UIViewController *'" - I genuinely tried to look in RecordDataViewController.h and couldn't make sense of this. Like I said, bad with computers, not sure why I'm having this issue, and I know that it's probably something basic.

If anyone would be willing to help me out with how to deal with issues like this, that would be great. Thanks, and sorry for my incompetence.

Answer (score 0):

The red are called errors. The yellow are called warnings. I'm going to suggest you look at a few beginning Xcode/iOS programming tutorials so you understand the basic concepts of how view controllers, arrays, etc. work in objective-c. The best place to start for someone completely new as yourself is here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks pretty helpful to me! Thanks a ton!